# Proper way to pass Object to Fragment Activity and write to Object from Fragments

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist, android-fragments

I want to pass an ArrayList of custom Objects to a `FragmentActivity`. Each `Fragment` will have information populated by an individual Object.

My question is, when I use the `set` methods (in the custom Object) in each `Fragment`, will that correctly update my ArrayList of these custom Objects so that I can pass this updated ArrayList of Objects to another `Activity`?

Comment: Its complicated.. Activities & Fragments should get arguments via Intents / Bundle and they must be serializable in some way (`Parcellable`) because the system can restart your app & fragments with deserialized copies of your original objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as the reference to the object is the same the changes are made.